# jCombo Box With Hidden Data java

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I've searched on how to put extra data in jComboBox in java, the most results that I've found is to create an Item Class that contains to attributes key and value.

I've done that but i'm still having this error whene i'm trying to add item in jComboBox with `new Item(key, value),

error code is  :

> Item cannot be converted to String
>           jComboTemp1.addItem(new Item("CA", "Canada"));

Here is the class Item :

```
public class Item {

    private int id;
    private String description;

    public Item(int id, String description) {
        this.id = id;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return description;
    }
}
```

The problem shows here although i've override toString methode  :

```
jComboTemp1.addItem(new Item<String>("CA", "Canada"));
```

Comment: Post a real program, a [mcve] that shows your problem. You will want to change your JComboBox and its model to `JComboBox<Item>` and `DefaultComboBoxModel<Item>` types. Then to display properly either override Item's `toString()` as you're doing, or give the combo box a renderer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several problems:

```
public class Item {
```

The class does not use generic.

```
public Item(int id, String description) {
```

The constructor is expecting an "int" and a "String".

```
jComboTemp1.addItem(new Item<String>("CA", "Canada"));
```

When you create the Item object you have two mistakes:

1. You are attempting to use generics
2. You pass the wrong parameters.

So you have two solutions. You need to either:

1. Use generics properly, or
2. Don't use generics.

If you don't use generics then you need to pass the proper parameters to the `Item` object:

```
jComboTemp1.addItem(new Item(1, "Canada"));
```

If you do want to use generics, then you need to modify the `Item` class to use generics.

Check out the `Item` class found in [Combo Box With Hidden Data](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2013/02/18/combo-box-with-hidden-data/) for a generic `Item` object. This object is a more complete implementation since it also implements the `equals(...)` and `hashcode()` methods.

Using the `Item` class from the above link if you want to have `Integer` data in your `Item` class you would use:

```
JComboBox<Item<Integer>> jcomboTemp1 = new JComboBox<Item<Integer>>();
...
jcomboTemp1.addItem(new Item<Integer>(1, "Canada"));
```

Using a generic object is a little more complicated but you get the added safety of compile time checks to make sure you add the proper data to the class.

A generic class is more reusable. You could easily change the code to be:

```
JComboBox<Item<String>> jcomboTemp1 = new JComboBox<Item<String>>();
...
jcomboTemp1.addItem(new Item<String>("CA", "Canada"));
```

and now the class supports a hidden value in a String format and no change was needed to the `Item` class.

Answer (score 0):

Instead to :

```
jComboTemp1.addItem(new Item<String>("CA", "Canada"));
```

Use :

```
jComboTemp1.addItem("CA");
jComboTemp1.addItem("Canada");
```

Or

```
jComboTemp1.addItem(new Item(1, "CA"));
jComboTemp1.addItem(new Item(2, "Canada"));
```

You have a constructor `Item(int, String)` and not `Item(String)`

Answer (score 0):

You do not provide enough code here:

What Item class do you use here:

```
jComboTemp1.addItem(new Item<String>("CA", "Canada"));
```

You instantiate a generic class but your Item class is no generic class

the following code works for me

```
class Item {
    private final int id;
    private final String name;
    public Item(int id, String name) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName();
    }
 }


JComboBox<Item> combobox = new JComboBox<Item>();       
combobox.addItem(new Item(4711, "name1"));
combobox.addItem(new Item(4712, "name2"));
combobox.addItem(new Item(4713, "name3"));
```

Comment: I only created a small example but I will correct my answer

Comment: *"I will correct my answer"* I don't think your answer was ever 'wrong'. The problem here is that the question needs clarification, as the OP in some parts of the question implies that the 2 pieces of information are a string abbreviation of a country name, and a country name, while other parts of the question imply the 2 pieces are an integer and string based country name. Perhaps they need to expand `Item` to incorporate *an integer **&** 2 strings*, but ultimately, they need to decide (& tell us) what exactly it is that an `Item` needs to contain.